# Amazon S3 copyObject using PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to copy a 1TB file from one bucket to another. I know that this can be done easily if I log into the AWS S3 panel but I would like to do it using PHP.

I am using the following [AWS S3 class from github](https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class/)

```
public static function copyObject($srcBucket, $srcUri, $bucket, $uri, $acl = self::ACL_PRIVATE, $metaHeaders = array(), $requestHeaders = array(), $storageClass = self::STORAGE_CLASS_STANDARD)
    {
        $rest = new S3Request('PUT', $bucket, $uri, self::$endpoint);
        $rest->setHeader('Content-Length', 0);
        foreach ($requestHeaders as $h => $v) $rest->setHeader($h, $v);
        foreach ($metaHeaders as $h => $v) $rest->setAmzHeader('x-amz-meta-'.$h, $v);
        if ($storageClass !== self::STORAGE_CLASS_STANDARD) // Storage class
            $rest->setAmzHeader('x-amz-storage-class', $storageClass);
        $rest->setAmzHeader('x-amz-acl', $acl);
        $rest->setAmzHeader('x-amz-copy-source', sprintf('/%s/%s', $srcBucket, rawurlencode($srcUri)));
        if (sizeof($requestHeaders) > 0 || sizeof($metaHeaders) > 0)
            $rest->setAmzHeader('x-amz-metadata-directive', 'REPLACE');

        $rest = $rest->getResponse();
        if ($rest->error === false && $rest->code !== 200)
            $rest->error = array('code' => $rest->code, 'message' => 'Unexpected HTTP status');
        if ($rest->error !== false)
        {
            self::__triggerError(sprintf("S3::copyObject({$srcBucket}, {$srcUri}, {$bucket}, {$uri}): [%s] %s",
            $rest->error['code'], $rest->error['message']), __FILE__, __LINE__);
            return false;
        }
        return isset($rest->body->LastModified, $rest->body->ETag) ? array(
            'time' => strtotime((string)$rest->body->LastModified),
            'hash' => substr((string)$rest->body->ETag, 1, -1)
        ) : false;
    }
```

I am using it in my PHP code as follows:

```
$s3 = new S3(AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY);
$s3->copyObject($srcBucket, $srcName, $bucketName, $saveName, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ_WRITE);
```

I'm getting no error_log. What am I doing wrong that I am missing, please?

Answer (score 1):

At 1 TB, the object is too large to copy in a single operation. To quote from the [S3 REST API documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectCOPY.html):

> You can store individual objects of up to 5 TB in Amazon S3. You create a copy of your object up to 5 GB in size in a single atomic operation using this API. **However, for copying an object greater than 5 GB, you must use the multipart upload API.**

Unfortunately, it doesn't appear that the S3 class you're using supports multipart uploads, so you'll need to use something else. I'd strongly recommend that you use [Amazon's AWS SDK for PHP](https://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/) — it's a bit bigger and more complex than the one you're using right now, but it supports the entirety of the S3 API (as well as other AWS services!), so it'll be able to handle this operation.

Comment: In my case I cannot use Amazon's SDK as my host is refusing to install it for me.

Comment: You don't need to have them install it. Just put it on your PHP include path (or, if you're really desperate, just in the domain directory).

Comment: Hi, do you have a link to a tutoria to learn how to go about it please? Thanks